# Sed command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code:

```
if [ -d "$PATH" ]; then
ABSPATH=$( cd "`echo "$1" | sed 's/[^/]*$//'`";pwd)
fi
```

when I run it, I get this `sed: command not found`.Any command I put inside this "if" blog writes this message, XXX:command not found. I have no idea why. I have exactly the same code elsewhere in my script and it is fine there.

Comment: em... maybe you can explain a little what are you trying to do. since i am not sure `-d "$PATH"` and your `ABSPATH` is going to be what you want. there may be some context code that introduces this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The nature of your program* snippet implies that you have just overwritten `PATH`. `PATH` is an important [environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html) that lets the shell know where to find commands… commands like `sed`. If you overwrite it, `sed` will not be found.

Use another name; even lowercase `path` will work fine.

*I'm fairly confident that you overwrote PATH because PATH should not be a directory – it should be a colon-separated list of directories. If `[ -d $PATH ]` is true it either implies you have a very restrictive context for PATH, or, more likely, you have overwritten it.